# eval return int and not list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

when I execute the following code in python, i get an error saying, "TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()". But the same commands work in an interpreter individually.

```
for line in inputFile:
    newline = line.strip()
    print len(newline)
    mylist = eval(newline)
    print len(mylist)
```

Will the eval command on a line string return a list or a int value? Please help.

Comment: you can `print type(mylist)` to find it out

Comment: And what input are you giving this? What `eval()` returns depends **entirely** on the input, without that input we cannot say anything.

Comment: Input is something like this, "[“A”, [“B”, [“C”, “D”], “E”], “F”]". I want the output in list format to handle individual elements in the list.

Comment: print type(mylist) returns as list, "<type 'list'>"

Comment: Found the problem. One of the input lines had just digits. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html), you can see that *eval* will return whatever the python expression will yield when evaluated (like when you press enter in the interpreter). So, if the input file has this line :

```
2 + 2
```

Then

```
eval("2+2")
```

on this will return 4, which is an int and has no length.